# Intermittent error when executing `az login`

Tags: azure-cli

I have build agents that started intermittently encountering a CLIInternalError about 2 days ago. Unfortunately, the agents are spun up and torn down as needed so I have no way of executing the `az feedback` command to report the issue. Has anyone encountered the error below, or have any advice on how I could go about troubleshooting this issue?

```
az login --service-principal -u **** -p **** --tenant ****
CLIInternalError: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
cannot import name 'ARMHttpLoggingPolicy' from 'azure.mgmt.core.policies' (/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/mgmt/core/policies/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 215, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 659, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 722, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 715, in _run_job
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 693, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 330, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 784, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/profile/custom.py", line 162, in login
    use_cert_sn_issuer=use_cert_sn_issuer)
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 211, in find_subscriptions_on_login
    username, sp_auth, tenant, self._ad_resource_uri)
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 901, in find_from_service_principal_id
    result = self._find_using_specific_tenant(tenant, token_entry[_ACCESS_TOKEN])
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 995, in _find_using_specific_tenant
    client = self._arm_client_factory(token_credential)
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 834, in create_arm_client_factory
    client_type = self._get_subscription_client_class()
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/_profile.py", line 1013, in _get_subscription_client_class
    from azure.cli.core.vendored_sdks.subscriptions import SubscriptionClient
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/vendored_sdks/subscriptions/__init__.py", line 9, in 
    from ._subscription_client import SubscriptionClient
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/vendored_sdks/subscriptions/_subscription_client.py", line 17, in 
    from ._configuration import SubscriptionClientConfiguration
  File "/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/vendored_sdks/subscriptions/_configuration.py", line 15, in 
    from azure.mgmt.core.policies import ARMHttpLoggingPolicy
ImportError: cannot import name 'ARMHttpLoggingPolicy' from 'azure.mgmt.core.policies' (/tools/azurecli/azurecli-2.17.1/env-2.17.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/mgmt/core/policies/__init__.py)
To open an issue, please run: 'az feedback'
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening due to library version conflicts.

If this is a self-hosted agent, you can try upgrading to the latest version of Azure CLI. If this issue is occurring on a Microsoft-hosted agent, you can report the issue on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) for Azure DevOps.

There is a similar issue reported with Azure CLI repo as well. You could follow updates to [#16873](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16873) or report a new issue with the above error log here: [Bug report](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/new/choose)